# firebase deploy not working even though firebase init command has worked

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I'm a newbie in programming and still learning some stuff (i use windows btw).

i try to make an app, connect it to firebase. after setting up everything its time to setting the CLI

good news : i successfully setting up everything from node to nvm until successfully launch the login in CLI.

bad news : right after successfully login the CLI, i'm trying to type in the cmd

```
firebase deploy --only function
```

and this error appear

> Error: not in a Firebase app directory (could not locate firebase.json)

i already search the web for the solution, but i found nothing.

can someone tell me did i miss something ?

Comment: can you post a structure of your files ? and where did you run the command ?

Comment: I ran it in windows powershell

Comment: I ran the command in windows powershell.

Comment: send me a screenshot of that command in powershell, make sure the path is correct